# How to execute ant using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ant, cmd

I have installed ant and it runs successfully in cmd. I know that when you want to use ant, you can enter the destination path and execute ant in command line. This works fine for me. But when I create a batch file to run ant in the destination path. It tells me that ant is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So here is what I want to know: how to execute ant in a batch file or is there another way to run it without entering *cd* command all the time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"c:\directory\where\ant\is\ant" -buildfile "d:\directory\where\your\build.xml\is\"`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But Still don't know why do I have to enter the full path of it since I only need to type 'java' in a batch file to execute a java program...

Comment: Java command is directly executable because it resides in windows\system32, and windows\system32 is included in path environment variable. BUT ant binary directory is not included in path. You can include it and then you will not need to include the full path.

Comment: But I have already added the ant path in system path environment variable. And I am able to run it by just typing 'ant' using the command prompt provided by windows. However, when it comes to a .bat file, it just doesn't work.

Comment: I've downloaded ant and tryed. In my PC everything works as expected, including to call ant from batch file. BUT, ant core (java code) is invoked from a bat file (`ant.bat`). So to call it from your batch file, `call ant` should be used. AND in the ant directory there is an ant.bat and ant.cmd, but ant.cmd is not an windows batch file. So calling it instead of ant.bat will generate the non recognized command error.

Comment: Everything is working as I expected after I deleted the ant.cmd file, looks like it's actually calling `ant.cmd` instead of `ant.bat` the last several times I tried.

Answer (score 1):

**call ant -f %BUILDXML_LOC% -lib %ANTUNITLIB_HOME%**

The above command must work. Just give it a try.

Where %BUILDXML_LOC% is the location where you have your build.xml file
and %ANTUNITLIB_HOME% is the location where you have placed your ant-antunit-1.2.jar and additional jars required

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting your `ANT_HOME` in your batch script? e.g.
(syntax may be slightly out of kilter)

```
SET ANT_HOME=C:\path\to\ant\directory
SET PATH=%PATH%\%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM allows ant to be invoked from commandline without changing
REM windows configuration.  Place in %HOME%/bin and name ant.bat.
REM You will need to add %HOME%\bin to %PATH%, but once bin is
REM added to path you will not need to add it again for other commands.

SET ANT_HOME=C:\Users\Username\TOOLS\apache-ant-1.10.1

SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin:%PATH%

"%ANT_HOME%\bin\ant" %*
```

I put that script in `C:\Users\username\bin` and name it `ant.bat`

I then modify the PATH once to add the bin folder.  After that I can add any number of commands in bin without having to mess with changing path.

The %* passes whatever was passed on the commandline to ant.  So then I can run ant like any other utility on the commandline or from another script like I would in bash.